# What's the difference between "wrap" and "wind"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference, vocabulary

I've looked them up in several dictionaries, but I find them very similar in meaning because both mean to turn something around something else, for example:
She wound a scarf around her neck.
She wrapped a scarf around her neck.

Comment: So **one** meaning of _wrap_ is close to **one** meaning of _wind_. Like most words they each have a range of meanings, most of which do not overlap. The primamry meaning of _wrap_ is to enclose something in some sort of sheet of material. The primary meaning of _wind_ is to turn or twist something.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose native speakers would answer better, but according to Cambridge dictionary, **wrap** doesn't necessarily mean **around**. [You can cover something with a piece of material](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wrap) in order to "wrap" it.

But **wind** implies that something turns, so if you "wind" a scarf, you wind it around a neck. You can't just lay down the scarf on the neck and say you've wound it.

Comment: I would wrap a sheet around something, but wind a string or rope around it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, now I see this slight difference and that my answer isn't good. =(

Comment: Mind you, the sheet that dead people used to be wrapped in when they were buried, is called a 'winding sheet'.

Comment: You wrap a scarf, but you wind a strangling rope, around a neck.

Answer (score 0):

- You wrap a package with or in paper.
- You can wrap an object with any type of material like paper or cloth or even chocolate. It means to surround the object completely with the material.
- Wind is different: **wind** means that a string or steel cable or thread (or anything like that, a filament) is put around and around some object. **Winding means has been placed around something round and is circular in motion**. **Wrapping envelops an object.**
- Thread is wound (wind, wound, wound) on a spool.
- Spools are have thread or filaments wound around them.

wind and winding is used a lot with images:

- to wind someone around your finger [get them to do what you want]
- to wind someone up [BrE, to make them believe something that is not true]
- roads are said to wind through places.
- Song: Long and Winding Road

If something like a road winds through a landscape, it is not straight. It has curves in it.

Well, that's the short of it but probably not the long of it. [idiom: the short and long of something]

She wound the scarf around her neck means the neck is like the spool and the scarf is like the thread. For this, the scarf must be long and thin. A short scarf would not work here.

She wrapped the scarf around her neck means she enveloped her neck with the scarf, like a package is wrapped with paper.